# how to make a very simple alarm app in android?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, alarm, timepicker

I read this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/AlarmClock.html)

and also I search through out I came to know that this can be done by using Timepicker and `constants EXTRA_HOUR and EXTRA_MINUTE`  but there is no systematic way how to do this . I'm confused how to proceed I'm new in android development please any help ?

can I call the inbuilt alarm features in android phones but when it rang my app will open to stop this because I want to add some features in stopping of alarm.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to start a couple levels about the `AlarmClock` class.

I suggest you start here

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html?hl=it

Comment: I've already gone through this my basics of android are clear

Comment: I am not sure what your question is then, please post what code you have so far.